# В чем смысл дублирования RoutePrefixAttribute сразу в двух пространствах имен?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Класс RoutePrefixAttibute расположен сразу в двух неймспейсах: System.Web.Mvc и System.Web.Http
Есть ли в этом какой-то смысл?

Comment: Вы уверены, что он в System.Web.Http есть? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.http

Comment: У вас ссылка на core, а у меня mvc 5, может в этом дело. Вот я из студии сделал [скриншот](https://imgur.com/ykyDRDs) К тому же, если указать сразу два этих пространства, возникает конфликт на имени класса.

Comment: Ну, видать, mvc5 уже на столько старый, что документацию убрали. =)

Comment: В пространстве имён System.Web.Mvc находится атрибут, относящийся к фреймворку ASP.NET MVC, этот фреймворк появился первым. В System.Net.Http живёт ASP.NET Web API, переиспользовать существующий класс было нельзя, потому, как MVC зависит от System.Web, а в Web API эту зависимость как раз таки убрали. Вот поэтому.